# EFcreate table with double quotes ODAC Error: ORA-00942

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, entity-framework

I'm migrating a proyect with SQL Server to Oracle with ODAC. NET 4.0 and Entity Framework 6.
I could access to this base and create tables but when EF try to read this tables I have this Exception: Error: ORA-00942. I check this tables in DB, Its exist but if I try to look the content with this (`select * from table`) I have an error "The table dont exist" but if I try with double quotes I can (`select * from "table"`).

I put some code in entitys to select my schema because without this I have others exceptions:

```
 public class ChatEntities : DbContext
    {
        public ChatEntities(): base ("ChatContext")
        {
        }      
        public DbSet<ChatUser> ChatUser { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Chat> Chat { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ChatPeople> ChatPeople { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ChatHistory> ChatHistory { get; set; }      

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {           
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("PROYECT");         
            modelBuilder.Entity<ChatUser>().ToTable("ChatUser", schemaName: "PROYECT");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Chat>().ToTable("Chat", schemaName: "PROYECT");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ChatPeople>().ToTable("ChatPeople", schemaName: "PROYECT");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ChatHistory>().ToTable("ChatHistory", schemaName: "PROYECT");    
        }
    }
```

And this is my DbMigration code:

```
  string  schema = "PROYECT.";
        public override void Up()
        {
            CreateTable(
                schema + "Chats",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 10, scale: 0, identity: true),
                        AdminId = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 10, scale: 0),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

            CreateTable(
                schema + "ChatHistories",
                c => new
                    {
                        Id = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 10, scale: 0, identity: true),
                        ChatId = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 10, scale: 0),
                        UserId = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 10, scale: 0),
                        Message = c.String(),
                        Date = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    })
                .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
                .ForeignKey(schema + "Chats", t => t.ChatId, cascadeDelete: true)
                .Index(t => t.ChatId);
```

.........

And in each Class I put this data annotation

```
  [Table("ChatHistory", Schema = "PROYECT")]    
    public class ChatHistory
    {       
        [Key]     
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ChatId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
     }
```

I read in other post that I need put the Schema in UpperCase and I have this but EF create all tables with double quotes and after doesnt find this tables.

Any idea or solution, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Oracle stores table and other objects names in upper case.  This can be overriden by enclosing the object name in double quotes `"`.  Since you are able to access the table by surrounding it's name in double quotes, it means that the tables was created with a mixed case name.

You will need to surround any object names with double quotes in order to access them if they were stored in any case other than all upper case.

If you change your migration code to store the table name in upper case, then you won't need the double quotes to access your tables.

Comment: I recently try to do this. Put ToUpper() method in table names In DbContext but Its only create the first table, in this case CHATS but only this one and I can access ok, after I have this exception "ora-00955 name is already used by an existing object"

Comment: Try `select * from all_objects where object_name = 'YOUR_OBJ_NAME'` to see what type of object is already using the name you are trying to create.

Comment: Ex. I try to do this   var user= db.ChatUser.Count(); I have this exception and with this query I generate one registry with OWNER:PROYECT and OBJECT_TYPE:TABLE both ok. I dont know why but Migrations only create one table of 4

Comment: I didnt see all the context I needed do this: `select * from all_objects where upper(object_name) like '%CHAT%' order by object_type` I have a new problem hope you could help me, EF create all tables but when I execute the application, migrations try to generate this tables again and dont recognize the last generated, and again Error: ORA-00955

Answer (score 0):

Casing in ORACLE and the confusion of using quotes can easily throw you off.  When it comes to ORACLE, just use all caps.  This example is .NET framework Identity integration with Oracle using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework NuGet package.  The All CAPS up scripts:

```
------------------------------------------------------------- */
-- Add sequences                                                          */
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

CREATE SEQUENCE SQ_ASPNETUSERCLAIMS
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 1
    NOMAXVALUE
    nocycle
    noorder
/

-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
-- Add tables                                                             */
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
-- Add table "ASPNETUSERS"                                                */
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

CREATE TABLE ASPNETUSERS (
    ID NVARCHAR2(128) CONSTRAINT NN_ANU_ID NOT NULL,
    EMAIL NVARCHAR2(256),
    EMAILCONFIRMED NUMBER(1) CONSTRAINT NN_ANU_EMAILCONFIRMED NOT NULL,
    PASSWORDHASH NCLOB,
    SECURITYSTAMP NCLOB,
    PHONENUMBER NCLOB,
    PHONENUMBERCONFIRMED NUMBER(1) CONSTRAINT NN_ANU_PHONENUMBERCONFIRMED NOT NULL,
    TWOFACTORENABLED NUMBER(1) CONSTRAINT NN_ANU_TWOFACTORENABLED NOT NULL,
    LOCKOUTENDDATEUTC DATE,
    LOCKOUTENABLED NUMBER(1) CONSTRAINT NN_ANU_LOCKOUTENABLED NOT NULL,
    ACCESSFAILEDCOUNT NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT NN_ANU_ACCESSFAILEDCOUNT NOT NULL,
    USERNAME NVARCHAR2(256) CONSTRAINT NN_ANU_USERNAME NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ASPNETUSERS PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
/

-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
-- Add table "ASPNETROLES"                                                */
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

CREATE TABLE ASPNETROLES (
    ID NVARCHAR2(128) CONSTRAINT NN_ANR_ID NOT NULL,
    NAME NVARCHAR2(256) CONSTRAINT NN_ANR_NAME NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ASPNETROLES PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
/

-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
-- Add table "ASPNETUSERROLES"                                            */
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

CREATE TABLE ASPNETUSERROLES (
    USERID NVARCHAR2(128) CONSTRAINT NN_ANUR_USERID NOT NULL,
    ROLEID NVARCHAR2(128) CONSTRAINT NN_ANUR_ROLEID NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ASPNETUSERROLES PRIMARY KEY (USERID, ROLEID)
)
/

-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
-- Add table "ASPNETUSERLOGINS"                                           */
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

CREATE TABLE ASPNETUSERLOGINS (
    LOGINPROVIDER NVARCHAR2(128) CONSTRAINT NN_ANUL_LOGINPROVIDER NOT NULL,
    PROVIDERKEY NVARCHAR2(128) CONSTRAINT NN_ANUL_PROVIDERKEY NOT NULL,
    USERID NVARCHAR2(128) CONSTRAINT NN_ANUL_USERID NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ASPNETUSERLOGINS PRIMARY KEY (LOGINPROVIDER, PROVIDERKEY, USERID)
)
/

-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
-- Add table "ASPNETUSERCLAIMS"                                           */
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

CREATE TABLE ASPNETUSERCLAIMS (
    ID NUMBER(10) CONSTRAINT NN_ANUC_ID NOT NULL,
    USERID NVARCHAR2(128) CONSTRAINT NN_ANUC_USERID NOT NULL,
    CLAIMTYPE NCLOB,
    CLAIMVALUE NCLOB,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ASPNETUSERCLAIMS PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
/

-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
-- Add foreign key constraints                                            */
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERLOGINS ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ASPNETUSERLOGINS_USERID 
    FOREIGN KEY (USERID) REFERENCES ASPNETUSERS (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
/

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERCLAIMS ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ASPNETUSERCLAIMS_USERID 
    FOREIGN KEY (USERID) REFERENCES ASPNETUSERS (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
/

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERROLES ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ASPNETUSERROLES_USERID 
    FOREIGN KEY (USERID) REFERENCES ASPNETUSERS (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
/

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERROLES ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ASPNETUSERROLES_ROLEID 
    FOREIGN KEY (ROLEID) REFERENCES ASPNETROLES (ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
/

-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
-- Add triggers                                                           */
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TR_ASPNETUSERCLAIMS       
BEFORE INSERT ON ASPNETUSERCLAIMS
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SELECT SQ_ASPNETUSERCLAIMS.nextval INTO :new.ID FROM dual;
END;
/
```

Code in IdentityModel.cs to map to the all caps:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // user id of owner
    var ownerSchema = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["OwnerSchema"];
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(ownerSchema);

    // the identity framework is looking for table and column names that are camel cased
    // however, our scripts don't force camel casing (we don't put quotes around our table and column names in the deltas)
    // therefore, we need to tell the identity framework to look for the all CAPS versions of the tables and columns

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("ASPNETROLES", adminSchema);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().Property(p => p.Name).HasColumnName("NAME");

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("ASPNETUSERCLAIMS");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().Property(p => p.UserId).HasColumnName("USERID");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().Property(p => p.ClaimType).HasColumnName("CLAIMTYPE");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().Property(p => p.ClaimValue).HasColumnName("CLAIMVALUE");

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("ASPNETUSERLOGINS");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().Property(p => p.LoginProvider).HasColumnName("LOGINPROVIDER");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().Property(p => p.ProviderKey).HasColumnName("PROVIDERKEY");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().Property(p => p.UserId).HasColumnName("USERID");

    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("ASPNETUSERROLES");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().Property(p => p.UserId).HasColumnName("USERID");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().Property(p => p.RoleId).HasColumnName("ROLEID");

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("ASPNETUSERS");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.UserName).HasColumnName("USERNAME");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.TwoFactorEnabled).HasColumnName("TWOFACTORENABLED");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.SecurityStamp).HasColumnName("SECURITYSTAMP");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.PhoneNumberConfirmed).HasColumnName("PHONENUMBERCONFIRMED");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.PhoneNumber).HasColumnName("PHONENUMBER");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(P => P.PasswordHash).HasColumnName("PASSWORDHASH");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.LockoutEndDateUtc).HasColumnName("LOCKOUTENDDATEUTC");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.LockoutEnabled).HasColumnName("LOCKOUTENABLED");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("ID");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.EmailConfirmed).HasColumnName("EMAILCONFIRMED");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.Email).HasColumnName("EMAIL");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Property(p => p.AccessFailedCount).HasColumnName("ACCESSFAILEDCOUNT");

}
```

If you're interested, drop scripts to roll back:

```
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
-- Drop triggers                                                          */
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

DROP TRIGGER TR_ASPNETUSERCLAIMS;

-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
-- Drop foreign key constraints                                           */
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERLOGINS DROP CONSTRAINT FK_ASPNETUSERLOGINS_USERID
/

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERCLAIMS DROP CONSTRAINT FK_ASPNETUSERCLAIMS_USERID
/

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERROLES DROP CONSTRAINT FK_ASPNETUSERROLES_USERID
/

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERROLES DROP CONSTRAINT FK_ASPNETUSERROLES_ROLEID
/

-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
-- Drop table "ASPNETUSERCLAIMS"                                          */
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

-- Drop constraints */

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERCLAIMS DROP CONSTRAINT NN_ANUC_ID
/

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERCLAIMS DROP CONSTRAINT NN_ANUC_USERID
/

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERCLAIMS DROP CONSTRAINT PK_ASPNETUSERCLAIMS
/

DROP TABLE ASPNETUSERCLAIMS
/

-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
-- Drop table "ASPNETUSERLOGINS"                                          */
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

-- Drop constraints */

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERLOGINS DROP CONSTRAINT NN_ANUL_LOGINPROVIDER
/

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERLOGINS DROP CONSTRAINT NN_ANUL_PROVIDERKEY
/

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERLOGINS DROP CONSTRAINT NN_ANUL_USERID
/

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERLOGINS DROP CONSTRAINT PK_ASPNETUSERLOGINS
/

DROP TABLE ASPNETUSERLOGINS
/

-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
-- Drop table "ASPNETUSERROLES"                                           */
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

-- Drop constraints */

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERROLES DROP CONSTRAINT NN_ANUR_USERID
/

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERROLES DROP CONSTRAINT NN_ANUR_ROLEID
/

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERROLES DROP CONSTRAINT PK_ASPNETUSERROLES
/

DROP TABLE ASPNETUSERROLES
/

-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
-- Drop table "ASPNETROLES"                                               */
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

-- Drop constraints */

ALTER TABLE ASPNETROLES DROP CONSTRAINT NN_ANR_ID
/

ALTER TABLE ASPNETROLES DROP CONSTRAINT NN_ANR_NAME
/

ALTER TABLE ASPNETROLES DROP CONSTRAINT PK_ASPNETROLES
/

DROP TABLE ASPNETROLES
/

-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
-- Drop table "ASPNETUSERS"                                               */
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

-- Drop constraints */

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERS DROP CONSTRAINT NN_ANU_ID
/

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERS DROP CONSTRAINT NN_ANU_EMAILCONFIRMED
/

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERS DROP CONSTRAINT NN_ANU_PHONENUMBERCONFIRMED
/

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERS DROP CONSTRAINT NN_ANU_TWOFACTORENABLED
/

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERS DROP CONSTRAINT NN_ANU_LOCKOUTENABLED
/

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERS DROP CONSTRAINT NN_ANU_ACCESSFAILEDCOUNT
/

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERS DROP CONSTRAINT NN_ANU_USERNAME
/

ALTER TABLE ASPNETUSERS DROP CONSTRAINT PK_ASPNETUSERS
/

DROP TABLE ASPNETUSERS
/

-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
-- Drop sequences                                                         */
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

DROP SEQUENCE SQ_ASPNETUSERCLAIMS
/
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. When I specified the `[Table("table_name")]` annotation, it was all lower-case.

Reading this thread caused me to rename the table annotation and place the name in upper-case... It WORKED!